# Return true if the value exist in all array

Tags: javascript, node.js

I want to return true if all the product contain `Done` in the `statusLog` array.  If any product does not contain `Done` in the `statusLog` then it should return false. Some product may not have `statusLog` property which mean it should return false.

The code seem to work fine, but I felt there must be a better way to refactor this. If "Done" not found from the first product then it should skip the loop as it no need to keep looping.  How can that be done?

```
data={"id":123,"products":[{"id":1,"name":"Item 1","statusLog":[{"name":"New"},{"name":"Done"}]},{"id":2,"name":"Item 2","statusLog":[{"name":"New"},{"name":"Done"}]},{"id":3,"name":"Item 3","statusLog":[{"name":"Pending"},{"name":"Dones"}]},]}

var hasDone = 0;

data.products.forEach((product) => {
  if (product.statusLog) {
     if (product.statusLog.some((status) => {
      return status.name == "Done"
    })) {
         hasDone++
    }
  }
});

if (hasDone != data.products.length) {
    console.log("All products has Done Status")
}
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/bdrve3xs/18/

Comment: You know how to use it in the inner loop, why not use it for the outer loop as well?

Comment: @RemcoGerlich Post answer for the outer loop

Comment: `return data.products.every(product  => product.statusLog.some(status`

Comment: @I'll-Be-Back: Paulpro already got there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.every](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every)

```
const allHaveDone = data.products.every( 
  product => (product.statusLog || []).some( status => status.name === "Done" )
);

if ( allHaveDone ) {
    console.log("All products has Done Status")
}
```

Comment: Should be `product.statusLog && product.statusLog.some( status => status.name === "Done" )` though, per OP's requirements.

Comment: @FelixKling Correct, `product.statusLog` may not exist

Answer (score 1):

You could use `filter` and check its length.

When done like this, you also get the *"not done"* ones in return.

Stack snippet

```js
data = {
  "id": 123,
  "products": [{
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Item 1",
      "statusLog": [{ "name": "New" }, { "name": "Done" }]
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Item 2",
      "statusLog": [{ "name": "New" }, { "name": "Done" }]
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "name": "Item 3",
      "statusLog": [{ "name": "Pending" }, { "name": "Dones" }]
    },
  ]
}

var not_done = data.products.filter(p => {
  if (!p.statusLog || !p.statusLog.some(s => s.name === "Done")) return p;
});

if (not_done.length > 0) {
  console.log('These/This is not "Done" yet', not_done)
}
```